# Is energy needed to release or absorb energy?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, work, mass-energy

Is energy itself needed to release or absorb energy? Or do all bodies have energy already to do work due to their mass ? Can light energy for eg. “absorb” more energy? For energy to be absorbed or released by a body, is some energy pre-required by that body?

Answer (score 0):

It depends! Let's take chemical reactions as an example.

Some reactions require an *activation energy* be added, in order to kickstart the reaction. For example, exposing gasoline to air does not cause it to instantly begin burning on its own- you need to add a little extra heat via a spark or a match, then the reaction will take off on its own and release a huge amount of heat.

Other reactions proceed spontaneously at room temperature, without the addition of any activation energy. For example, simply exposing dimethylhydrazine to dinitrogen tetroxide will instantly create a violent explosion, without the need for a spark or flame.